# UBIFS mount in busybox via fstab does not recognize relatime option

Tags: linux, busybox, ubifs, fstab

I am getting this error when I try to mount my UBIFS filesytem:

```
mount -o remount,rw /config
UBIFS error (pid 1265): ubifs_parse_options: unrecognized mount option "relatime" or
 missing value
```

The content of my fstab is :

```
root@drgos:~# cat /etc/fstab                                                        
# WARNING: this is an auto generated file, please use uci to set static filesystems 
/dev/ubi0_0     /config ubifs   ro    0       0
```

And when I type mount the result is :

```
root@drgos:~# mount                                                                 
rootfs on / type rootfs (rw)                                                        
none on /proc type proc (rw,relatime)                                               
none on /sys type sysfs (rw,relatime)                                               
tmpfs on /dev type tmpfs (rw,relatime,size=512k)                                    
none on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,relatime,mode=600)                                 
/dev/ubi0_0 on /config type ubifs (ro,relatime)                                     
none on /proc/bus/usb type usbfs (rw,relatime)
```

I do not understand why I have the option relatime since that one is not present in my fstab!

I am using BusyBox v1.11.2 (2014-01-13 09:35:41 CET) multi-call binary.

Answer (score 0):

These options are dependent on the Linux kernel version.  *relatime* is a general mount options.    *relatime* is the default for newer Linux kernels.  Other filesystems may quietly ignore unknown options, whereas *ubifs* is failing.  You can try `mount -o remount,rw,noatime,norelatime /config`.  Your `mount` command shows the */config* directory is mounted with *relatime*; this is information that *busybox* mount applet collected.

This information is collected with the [`getmntent_r()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getmntent_r) function.  If *busybox* is dynamically linked, then the 'C' library may be giving this information as part of the *mnt_opts* string.

The idea with `mount -o remount,rw,noatime,norelatime /config` is to try and over-ride this information so that UbiFs will be happy with its mount options.  The other way is to simply `umount` and then `mount` again manually.

```
 umount /config
 mount -t ubifs /dev/ubi0_0 /config
```

This way previous mount information will not be retrieved.